# Как запомнить рандом?

Tags: python, telebot

```
login = random.randint(1, 9)

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите этот код: " + str(login))
```

```
 if message.text == login:
     bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Круто, все верно!')
```

Как реализовать, что бы бот давал рандомный номер и продолжал работать, если пользователь введет этот номер? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так

```
def name_func(message: types.Message):
    login = random.randint(1, 9)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите этот код: " + str(login))
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, name_func_next, login)

def name_func_next(message: types.Message, login: int):
    if message.text == str(login):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Круто, все верно!')
```

Comment: Спасибо, забыл про str

Comment: А как сделать, чтоб каждому юзеру рандомный код, а то всем один и тот же дает

Comment: Ройте про random